# how to modify the default tcp implementation in linux kernel

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel

i am doing some simulations of DDOS SYN FLOOD attack on a real network using virtual machines and i want to modify the current behavior of TCP three-way-handshake on Linux Mint, can anyone give me a guide or the steps to do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the kernel code, then you need to know where they are, and then edit the code, compile them and run. Here is a [network](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/) can help you know how to do these things, but the knowledge of Linux network stack is not include.